# How can I make a template call a method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
          x:Class="Japanese.OpenPageTemplate"
          x:Name="this">
        <Label Text="ABC" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
 </ViewCell>
```

and the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese.Templates
{
    public partial class OpenPageTemplate : ViewCell
    {
        public OpenPageViewCellTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnTapped()
        {
            base.OnTapped();
            // I need to call openPage() here or at least have openPage() called from the place where the template is used.
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can make this template call a method called openPage() when the user taps on the ViewCell? In a previous question there was an answer about using the .Invoke method that went something like this:

```
ClickAction?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
```

However this time there's just one action to invoke and I don't need to pass information on the action into ClickAction.

Comment: Where would `openPage()` be defined?

Comment: You can expose an event or command that is invoked when tapped and have the users of the template assign an action to be performed when the template is tapped.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how the template will be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the ViewCell in a DataTemplate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DataTemplate xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:template="clr-namespace:Japanese"
          x:Class="Japanese.OpenPageTemplate">
  <ViewCell Tapped="OnOpenPageTapped">
    ...
  </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Codebehind:

```
namespace Japanese
{
  public partial class OpenPageTemplate : DataTemplate
  {
    public OpenPageTemplate ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private void OnOpenPageTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //example: template is an itemtemplate for a list of class A.B with property C
        var c = ((sender as ViewCell)?.BindingContext as A.B)?.C;
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to the desired [Cell.Tapped Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.cell.tapped?view=xamarin-forms) and invoke the action when the event is raised.

XAML

```xml
<template:OpenPageTemplate Tapped="OnOpenPageTapped" />
```

Code behind

```cs
private void OnOpenPageTapped(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    openPage();
}
```

assuming that `openPage()` is accessible from the place where the template is used.